# Why Do I Still Have java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setText in android.widget.Toast not mocked.?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I still have method not mocked when I clearly stated the when function from Mock. Any tips? Thank you in advance.
This is my test code that I have created to test the function.

```
@Test
    fun uploadStory() {

        val multi : MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "Test",
            "test",
        )
        val description = "test".toRequestBody(
            "text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        )

        val mockTest = mock(Toast::class.java)

        `when`(mockTest.setText("Story Uploaded Successfully")).then{
            doNothing()
        }


        `when`(mockTest.show()).then{
            doNothing()
        }

        val test = testStoryRepository.uploadStory(application.applicationContext,"Token", multi, description).equals(true)
        Assert.assertTrue(test)
    }
```

And this is the real uploadstory function from the repository. As you can see I indeed set a toast. Or am i doing it wrong?

```
fun uploadStory(
        context: Context,
        token: String,
        file: MultipartBody.Part,
        description: RequestBody
    ) {
        _isLoading.value = true
        val client = apiService.uploadImage(
            "Bearer $token", file, description
        )
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<UploadStoryResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<UploadStoryResponse>,
                response: Response<UploadStoryResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    _isLoading.value = false
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    if (responseBody != null && !responseBody.error) {

                        val toastStory = Toast(context)
                        toastStory.setText("Story Uploaded Successfully")
                        toastStory.show()
                        val intent = Intent(context, StoryListActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(context, intent, null)
                    }
                } else {
                    _isLoading.value = false

                    val toastStory = Toast.makeText(context, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    toastStory.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
                    toastStory.show()
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadStoryResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                _isLoading.value = false
                val toastStory = Toast.makeText(context, "Terjadi kesalahan!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toastStory.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
                toastStory.show()
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message.toString()}")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NFBowcd

Comment: Your toast is not actually being mocked since you instantiate it within your class.

Comment: So should make a new class to display the toast?

Comment: To use a mock, you'd need to pass it in from your test.

Comment: oh yeah i  fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding my toast outside the function as a parameter then modifying that toast inside it. Thanks!